# How to close matplotlib figure without loosing the sequence?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have tkinter class. In one of a method connected with a button, it is possible to view 2 curves saved in a external file.

```
self.btnView = tk.Button(master, text="View", width = 10, height =2, fg = "blue",command=self.ViewCurve)
```

The method is like:

```
def ViewCurve(self):
    ....
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,figsize=(8,6))
    ....
    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)
    print("end method")
```

My problem is quite simple. The figure comes up, but when I close it manually (with the x on the right top of the window), the code doesn't print the last string "end method". It seems like that I interrupt the sequence.
Another funny thing is: when I close my GUI with the command master. quit, I could see the string.
How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance